# Droplr background image/css?

Tags: html, css

I was wondering how I could do a background something like the home page of Droplr? It looks very cool, and want to use that as the background for my website. It is at https://droplr.com/hello.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a personalized background. Click here to have [it](https://d25ss6wjc6pfq2.cloudfront.net/assets/shared/light-gray-topo-hi-4e6a536475f8422cda9330175b32d3f3.png). After that, you need to add some css property to make the background fit to the screen :

From the source code of Droplr, I found :

```
.theElement {
    background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% #575A60;
    background-color: #575A60;
    background-image: none;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background-attachment: scroll;
    background-position: 0% 0%;
    background-clip: border-box;
    background-origin: padding-box;
    background-size: auto auto;
    color: #FFF;
    text-shadow: none;
}
```

Hope this help.